# Duplicating record in Entity Framework many to many relationship using Asp.net Boilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate

Im using asp.net boilerplate with entity framework. 
I have 2 entities: Product and Supplier with many to many relationship.

My problem: When i save a product with one or more suppliers, The product and the relation on supplierProduct table is saved but the supplier record is duplicated on supplier table.

I read that happens because there are 2 entities from different contexts, so i need "attach" the suppliers to Products context. I dont know how to do it. Someone can help me?

My entities:

```
public class Product : FullAuditedEntity
{

    public Product()
    {
        Suppliers = new HashSet<Supplier>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
}


public class Supplier : FullAuditedEntity
{
    public Supplier()
    {
        Products = new HashSet<Product>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

My domain service called ProductManager

```
public async Task<Product> Create(Product entity)
    {
        var product = _repositoryProduct.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == entity.Id);

        if (product != null)
        {
            throw new UserFriendlyException("Product already exists.");
        }
        else
        {
            return await _repositoryProduct.InsertAsync(entity);
        }
    }
```

My Application Service called ProductAppService:

```
public async Task Create(CreateProductInput input)
    {
        Product output = Mapper.Map<CreateProductInput, Product>(input);
        await _productManager.Create(output);
    }
```

My CreateProductInput Data transfer object

```
public class CreateProductInput
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
}
```

My angular component product-list-component

```
    // GET Products
    function getProducts() {
        productService.listAll()
            .then(function (result) {
                vm.users = result.data;
            });
    }
    getProducts();

    // GET Suppliers
    function getSuppliers() {
        supplierService.listAll()
            .then(function (result) {
                vm.suppliers = result.data;
            });
    }
    getSuppliers();

    //Save the data
    vm.save = function () {
        abp.ui.setBusy();
        productService.create(vm.product)
            .then(function () {
                abp.notify.info(App.localize('SavedSuccessfully'));
                $uibModalInstance.close();
            }).finally(function () {
                abp.ui.clearBusy();
                getProducts();
            });
    }
```

Comment: You haven't included the most relevant method implementation - `InsertAsync` of the `Product` repository.

Comment: Its a method from asp.net boilerplate https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate

Comment: Well, the default generic repository implementation is quite naïve and apparently does not work for entities with related data. Most likely you need to implement custom repository.

Comment: I think i need "Attach" the related entities somewhere.

Comment: Correct. And the question is where. I suggest implementing custom repository, override `InsertAsync` method and do it there.

Comment: Ivan Stoev, i created a custom repo and a method called InsertAndAttach where i manually attached the entities to the context and solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the Ivan Stoev comment i figure out how solve it. I implemented a custom repository and attached my entities to the dbcontext there.

[This link](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Repositories) shows in details how create a custom repository.

In resume:

1- Create a custom repository INTERFACE

2- Implement the custom repository+

3- Create a method there and use the `dbcontext.attach(entity)` to attach to the context the entity thats was duplicating and save the context.

4- Replace the IRepository used on domain service for the custom repository.

5- Use the custom created method and be happy.

Msg here if its not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is what happens in create method and what you pass to it.

```
public async Task<Product> Create(Product entity)
{
    var product = _repositoryProduct.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == entity.Id);

    if (product != null)
    {
        throw new UserFriendlyException("Product already exists.");
    }
    else
    {
        return await _repositoryProduct.InsertAsync(entity);
    }
}
```

To me it looks like parameter you pass to Create method will always have Id == 0 hence why it will always fall into else block and insert new entity

Thats because CreateProductInput does not have Id property to map from. So it will always map to product with default value for Id (int = 0).

Also you could pass ids of your Supplier entites and fetch them before calling Create, that way those should be automatically attached to DbContext and not duplicated

Comment: Hey user, tkx for the answer. I figure out how to solve this and ill post here soon